# iOS の「ショートカット」アプリに関する話題はオントピックですか？

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

最近、以下のような iOS のショートカットアプリに関する質問が投稿されました。

[YouTubeのダイレクトリンクを取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/72372)

この「[ショートカットアプリ (App Store)](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/id915249334)」というものは、iPhone 上で予め定義しておいた操作を簡単に呼び出せるアプリのようで、厳密に言えばソースコードを記述するようなプログラミングとは離れた話題に見える一方、"ロジックを組み立てる" という意味ではプログラミングっぽいと言えなくもありません。

件の質問に関しては現状「より詳細さが必要」などの理由でいくつかのクローズ票が入っていますが、「プログラミングか否か」の視点で考えた時に、スタック・オーバーフローにおいてオントピックでしょうか？

**参考:**
[Siri、ショートカット App、「Siri からの提案」でショートカットを実行する](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT209055)

Answer (score 1):

「より詳細さが必要」という意見は「アリ」だと思いますが、投票で閉じるよりは先ずコメントして改善を促した方が良いと思われます。

例えばIME関連は技術的な物の他に、単なる使い方の質問みたいなものも許容されている訳ですから。
['ime'を含む投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=IME)